# Why can't I getting connected to the Internet with Fedora-13?

Tags: internet-connection, fedora-13

I've installed **Fedora-13** recently with x86_64 DVD. I've configured to install it for the `Software Development`. For network domain I left as it is(`localhost.localdomain`)... My internet connection doesn't work with Fedora-13, but it does in Windows. Is there any configuration setting I missed?

Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this question. This will require troubleshooting your connection setup. As a first hint, check ifconfig output, i.e. open a console and enter "ifconfig" (as superuser).
Edit: Please also provide information about your infrastructure, i.e. are you connected directly to a modem or are you behind a NAT? Are you using DHCP?

Comment: I've connected directly from a Firewall.. That's it, not to any network...

Comment: So what's the ifconfig output? While you're at it also run
tracert google.com 
(again as superuser) and post the output.